# C++ delete pointer allocated twice

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand more about c++ pointers and freeing memory.
Let's say we have the following piece of code

```
int main{

  int * A = new int[4];
  int * B = new int[4];
  A = B;

  delete[] A;
  delete[] B;

  return 0;
}
```

A is pointing to a new created pointer, whereas B is pointing to another one,so we have a total of two pointers.
Now saying `A = B` means that A and B are now pointing to the same pointer. Therefore what happens to the other pointer in this case? And how can we delete it?

Comment: 1) It is lost forever, 2) You can't. P.S. "A nd B" are not "pointing to the same pointer".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what are they pointing at then?

Comment: `A = B;` and `delete[] A;` statements should be swapped to avoid memory leak.

Comment: They are pointing to `int`s. They are not pointing to another pointer.

Comment: I haven't used `new` or `delete` in the last 10 years.  There's no need to use them, except in some specialized circumstances (such as making your own smart pointer).  Instead, use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`, and for federated ownership `std::shared_ptr`.  For teachers of C++, they should defer teaching about `new` and `delete` for advanced classes.

Comment: @Eljay I didn't mention this but I was also trying to use a library with a function that takes an allocated pointer as parameter

Comment: @HasanH even then you shouldn't be using `new` ;). Smart pointers provide access to the pointer they manage if you need it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Therefore what happens to the other pointer in this case?

It is lost. You dropped the last reference to the array `A` was pointing to (`A` and `B` are not pointing to pointers. They are pointers and they do point at the first element of the arrays, ie `int`s, respectively).

> And how can we delete it?

You cannot. The memory is leaked.

Don't ever use raw owning pointers. For dynamic arrays you can use `std::vector` and for others you can use smart pointers. With `std::vector` your code would be:

```
#include <vector>
int main{
    auto A = std::vector<int>(4);
    auto B = std::vector<int>(4);
    A = B;
}
```

And for the sake of completeness also a leak-free version of your code:

```
void please_dont_do_this() {    
  int * A = new int[4];
  int * B = new int[4];

  delete [] A; // delete the array before the pointer is lost

  A = B;

  delete[] B;  // delete the array only once !    
}
```

PS: I know this view isnt very popular among enthusiastic beginners who want to learn as much as possible, but imho the most important thing you need to know about raw pointers in C++ is that you almost never need them (and when you think you need them then most likely you still don't).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. This was more than enough

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about pointers here.

```
int i = 3;
i = 4;
```

What happened to the 3? It's gone, overwritten by `i = 4`. Same thing with pointers:

```
int *p = new int[4];
int *q = new int[4];
```

`p` points at an array of `int` and `q` points at another array of `int`.

```
p = q;
```

The old value of `p` is gone, overwritten by `p = q`. `p` and `q` now hold the **same** pointer value, and that pointer points at the memory allocated by the second call to `new int[4]`.

To free the memory allocated in the first call to `new int[4]` you have to hold on to the pointer that `new` returned.